# Accessing a windows shared folder from Linux using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shared-directory

I've a shared folder created (with access to everyone) in Windows. on `C:\sharedfolder`, so I can access it with:

```
\\mylocalnetworkip\sharedfolder
```

Now I want a Python script to write stuff there from another machine.

If I run this simple script on Windows (from my machine, using Python under Windows), it works. It creates the file and writes that content.

```
file = open(r'\\mylocalnetworkip\sharedfolder\tester.dat', 'w')
file.write('whatever')
file.close()
```

But if I run the same script in Linux (from another machine, but still on my local network, this means if I ping my IP it works), it doesn't work.

With *it doesn't work* I mean that *it doesn't fail*, the strange thing that it creates a file on the same path with the name of the entire

```
root@mc:/tmp# python tester.py  <-- the script with the code above
root@mc:/tmp# ls
\\mylocalnetworkip\sharedfolder\tester.dat  tester.py
root@mc:/tmp# cat \\mylocalnetworkip\sharedfolder\tester.dat
whatever
root@mc:/tmp#
```

Can someone give me a hand and tell me how can I make it work in Linux? Thank you!

**PS:** I also tested it using `'\\\\mylocalnetworkip\\sharedfolder\\tester.dat'` with no luck.

Comment: Can you please show us the output of `root@mc:/tmp#  ls \\mylocalnetworkip\sharedfolder`. I think you must mount the shared folder first.

Comment: You have the `cat` on the code I provided. Its content is the `whatever` string, the thing you want to write.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I edited my first comment and added the `ls`. You have to "mount" the shared folder first into your linux filesystem. You can not access it before.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: No. Ask the internet. ;) Look here https://unix.stackexchange.com/ for example. You need to add more context informations (Linux system, type of shared folder, what you have tried so far, ...) if you ask it.

Comment: Are you sure I need to mount it before accessing it? This is because I'm using Linux? Why works directly from Windows? I tried to access a remote folder using Windows (not the one of my machine) and works too.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems here.

### Mounting

Linux is not able to handle paths like this `\\mylocalnetworkip\sharedfolder\tester.dat`.

On a Linux system you first have to "mount" a shared folder before you can use it. After mountig (depending on the mount point) the path could look like this `/mnt/mylocalnetworkip/sharedfolder/tester.dat`.

There are different ways to mount on Linux. e.g. check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18925/136851 or https://www.putorius.net/mount-windows-share-linux.html

### Path separators

Windows and Linux using different path separators. A fine solution in Python is to create a path like this.

```
import os
os.path.join('/', 'mnt', 'mylocalnetworkip', 'sharedfolder', 'tester.dat')
```

The result is

```
/mnt/mylocalnetworkip/sharedfolder/tester.dat
```

Be aware of the first `/` which indicates the root of the linux filesystem.

Comment: This doesn't work for network folders